# Is there way to make jpql/native-query zone agnostic

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a date field in our PostgreSQL table where date is being saved including time stamp and zone (using "localdatetime" in java side when capturing). But requirement is to pull up record checking only the date part (ignore the time and zone), so that all users from all over the world can see the same result if filter by date.

Please let me know should I provide more explanation.

Comment: It is never the same date all over the world. 2021-12-11 means something different in Japan and New York. So which same result do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Wrong data types means lost information

> postgres table where date is being saved including time stamp and zone ( using "localdatetime" in java side when capturing )

That is a contradiction in types.

The `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type in PostgreSQL does *not* save a time zone. Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) carefully. It explains that any time zone or offset information provided along with the date and time-of-day is used to adjust to an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. In other words, the date and time are adjusted “to UTC”, as we say in shorthand.

That zone or offset information you may have provided is then discarded.  Postgres does not remember the original offset or zone. Any value retrieved from a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is always in UTC. If you care about the original zone or offset, you must store that yourself in a second column.

But you have a problem. You did not provide *any* indicator of time zone or offset when sending the date-time to the database. You incorrectly used the `LocalDateTime` class which purposely lacks any indicator of time zone or offset. The `LocalDateTime` class represents a date with time-of-day, and nothing else. Thus the contradiction mentioned above. You provided two things (date, time-of-day) to a column that needs three things (date, time-of-day, and zone/offset).

I presume that Postgres took your `LocalDateTime` value and stored it as if it it were a date and time in UTC. So you have lost information.  For example, if one row’s input was meant to be noon on the 23rd of January 2022 in Tokyo Japan , while another row’s input was meant to be noon on that same 23rd date in Toulouse France , and yet a third row’s input was meant for noon also on that 23rd but as seen in Toledo Ohio US , then you will be incorrectly recording three different moments that happened several hours apart as if they all happened at another moment, a fourth moment, noon on the 23rd as seen in UTC, 2022-02-23T12:00Z.

After recording such a mish-mash of erroneous values, there is no going back. Unless you have a way of knowing for certain the intended zone of each row, your information is lost, and your stored column is worthless.

## Querying for a day

Let’s set aside the issue of having invalidly stored moments. Let’s now focus on the issue of how to query for a day’s worth of rows with a column of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

You need to understand that for any given moment, **the date varies** by time zone. At any moment it may be “tomorrow” in Sydney Australia  while simultaneously “yesterday” in Edmonton Alberta Canada . So you need the context of a time zone (or offset) to perceive a date.

If you want to query for a day as seen in Edmonton, specify the time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

Specify the desired date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Determine a span of time representing all the moments of that day. The best approach to define such a span is the Half-Open approach.  In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So the span starts with the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the following day.

To get start of day, let *java.time* determine that. Days do *not* always start at 00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime start = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

The `ZonedDateTime` does not map to any data type in SQL. So convert to an `OffsetDateTime` object for exchanging with the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odtStart = start.toOffsetDateTime() ; 
OffsetDateTime odtEnd = end.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Pass those through your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtEnd ) ;
```

In your SQL, do *not* use `BETWEEN`. That command is fully closed. For Half-Open, write your SQL query as looking for values that (a) are **not before the start** (“not before” is an abbreviated way of saying “is equal to or later than”), **and** (b) are **before the end**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 24.12.2021 15:00 Berlin (Germany) is in the database.

People from Germany will see 15:00.

But people from London must see either 16:00 or "15:00 wall clock in Berlin".

Since you said

```
from all over the world can see the same resut
```

There will be a difference between 15:00 and 16:00: the number 5 and the number 6, they are different.

You could give everyone the same results by printing

```
15:00 wall clock in Berlin
```

But this needs to transport the Timezone Berlin beside the datetime.